# Laravel 4 phpunit is doing nothing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I am trying to run the default testcase of laravel 4 for an app. Phpunit works when I explicitly mention the testfile path but doesn't seem to work otherwise, furthermore it returns 255 code when I try to run Phpunit only.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have phpunit installed globally or through composer? Do you have a phpunit.xml file in the root path of your application? Is it properly pointing to the test directory?

Comment: I have phpunit locally installed but it is in the $PATH. Also, I am running phpunit from the root of the laravel application which has phpunit.xml

Comment: And the installation was done via Composer. like this `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/arpaul/Work/src/personal/shikshamanthan/vendor/bin`

Comment: What does "phpunit -v" returns?

Comment: I think I got to the route, some tests are failing horribly and that's probably why phpunit is failing silently, but shouldn't it give some debug information may be.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your **phpunit.xml** file, there you will find bootstrap path to autoloader.

Are you using global PHPUNit framework or you are using local (installed with composer) ?

I created my vim mapping so it is pointing always to current file:

```
nmap ,t :!clear && phpunit %<esc>
```

Comment: I have it locally installed. I can see your mapping, my concern is phpunit.xml seems fine as when I give the full path of the testclass it reads the xml and works as expected. Only when I don't give any hint to phpunit as to what to run, I expect it to read the phpunit.xml of the directory where the command is issued and run as per the testsuites.